# if list contains any of list return matching string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column that compares two lists and returns the matching string.

I keep getting the error "'list' object has no attribute 'find'".

I'm still a novice at this so any help would be really appreciated!

I'm trying to use python and pandas for this

What I have so far is

```
raw = pd.read_csv(r"")
brandnames = ['Amana','Maytag']

raw['Brands'] = [k for k in raw['Description'] if brandnames.find(k)]

raw.head()
```

I want the end result to have a new column named Brands that say 'Amana' when the Description column contains the words 'Amana'

Thank you so much!

Comment: maybe instead of `if brandnames.find(k)` you wanted `if k in brandnames`? or better yet, take a look at the [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method: `raw["Brands"] = raw["Description"].isin(brandnames)`. For future references, it is a lot easier to answer a question if you provide some small sample input and output data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why *you* are confused.  The `find` documentation clearly states that it's a string method, not list.  Also, it returns an index.  You've invented a `find` method that returns a Boolean and is a new element of class `list`.

I think what you want is

```
[k for k in raw['Description'] if k in brandnames]
```

More directly, you could do this with set intersection.  Turn both name lists into sets, take the intersection, and convert to a list.

```
list(set(raw['Description']) * set(brandnames))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I'm still getting an error though saying that the length of values doesn't match the length of index

Answer (score 0):

There is no "find" method or property in the list type (brandnames), so Python is throwing an error. For a quick check of the available properties and methods in a type, you can use `dir()`, e.g.:

```
>>> x = ['abc', 'def']
>>> dir(x)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', ...
```

What you probably wanted was the `in` operator like in Prune's answer. One thing worth considering is that `in` will only return `True` if an *exact* match is found:

```
>>> brandnames = ['Amana', 'Maytag']
>>> 'Amana' in brandnames
True
>>> 'Amana ' in brandnames
False
>>> 'amana' in brandnames
False
>>> 'Amanaa' in brandnames
False
```

Another thing to consider is you may need to do make additional changes to result returned from `pd.read_csv` before you can use the `in` operator on it.

```
>>> some_data = "foo bar baz Maytag"
>>> [i for i in some_data.split(' ') if i in brandnames]
['Maytag']
```

Calling `type()` on `raw` in your program might work, but if not, I would suggest having a look at the Pandas documentation.